# "The type must implement the inherited abstract method Application.start(Stage)" while method is both included and overridden

Tags: java, object, javafx

Java FX noob, but I've tried all I know and can find from others on the web. I've verified the JVM to be at version 1.8 and cleaned/rebuilt the entire package.

Trying to make a program that displays 3 objects one after the other, forever on an empty background, until program crash/close, within a class called Painter. 
It is called/driven by a Controller class within the same package.

The methods in Painter are start(), run() and main(), the first two have errors as well as the class declaration itself.

The class declaration has the titular error.
run() is overridden but still has the complaint "must override or inherit a supertype method". 
start() has a few errors. I attempted to make it implement Application directly but it still complains about it.

```
package anonAssignment2; //@author anon, course#

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;                 
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;                      
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;                     
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;


import javafx.application.Application;              
import javafx.scene.Scene;                      
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;                        
//Handles animation timing
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Timer;     // ->
import java.lang.*;         //Thread.sleep(int milliseconds)


/* 
 * Painter- handles shape drawing
 * Extends application to be within spec, called by controller
 * Implements EventHandler for 3000ms changing of shape
 */

public class Painter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
    }


    Painter painter = new Painter();

    Pane pane = new Pane();

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();



    /** Method to start continuously displaying GUI shapes/objects
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void run() { 
    while(true) {                            
 //Always true, runs until program killed/crashes

        gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        gc.strokeOval(150, 150, 100, 100);  //circle
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);

        gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);   //For purposes of this program, blank background, clearing rectangle works

        gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        gc.strokeRect(100, 100, 100, 100);  //Square
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);

        gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        gc.strokeText("Course # and Title", 100, 140);  //Text, approximately centered
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);

        gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

        }

        }

    /**Start command, uses primaryStage instance 
     * Called by Controller
     * 
     */


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) implements Application throws Exception {
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    pane.setPrefWidth(300);
        pane.setPrefHeight(300);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rheault Project 2");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Controller instance = new Controller(painter);               
        //Controller constructor with argument of painter instance
    }

}

//controller.java class:

//@author anon, course #
package anonAssignment2;


public class Controller extends Thread {
    private Painter painter;
    public Controller(Painter painter) {
        this.painter = painter;
        Painter.start();
        }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            painter.paint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

''''

Comment: Hi! How much of this code have you tested? I tried copypasting your code into a java project and it looks like you're trying to run Application, from a mainthread..inside application? I'm just wondering if your code has worked before. Otherwise maybe this is the issue: public class Painter extends javafx.application.Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javafx.application.Application.launch(args);
    }

Comment: Also I looked at your start method. Changing to this, gives no errors directly at least:

Comment: @Override
    public void start(javafx.stage.Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        javafx.scene.layout.Pane pane = new javafx.scene.layout.Pane();

        pane.setPrefWidth(300);
        pane.setPrefHeight(300);
        javafx.scene.Scene scene = new javafx.scene.Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rheault Project 2");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Controller instance = new Controller(painter);
        //Controller constructor with argument of painter instance
    }

Comment: (I skipped the Implements part since it's already cleary you're overriding the superclass's method, you can even click on it in your IDE and it will go to the superclass method)

Comment: @Override
    public void run  <- this method doesn't actually overwrite anything. If you check the superclass, Application. There is no run method in it.

Comment: Your code flow is all wrong. Also, don't use Thread. Try using Something from `Animation`. Maybe `Timeline`.

Comment: None of the code was tested, it would need to compile to be tested. The start method you posted doesn't give me any errors, but I'm perplexed as to why, it's virtually identical to mine

Comment: This shouldn't compile at all. `implements Application` is nothing that is allowed in a method declaration (even if we ignore the fact that `Application` is not an interface). Also `@Override` should result in an error for `run`, since there is no such method to override in `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all copying your code into an IDE it seems like
you're trying to run an Application from a main inside..the application?
Like this:

```
  public class Painter extends javafx.application.Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       javafx.application.Application.launch(args);
   }
```

I think breaking out the painter class into it's own class would be a lot better.
You could still keep this main part in its own mainclass and just break out the painter logic.

Then I looked a bit at your code:

Changing your start method like this, gives me at least no errors in the IDE:

```
@Override
public void start(javafx.stage.Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    javafx.scene.layout.Pane pane = new javafx.scene.layout.Pane();

    pane.setPrefWidth(300);
    pane.setPrefHeight(300);
    javafx.scene.Scene scene = new javafx.scene.Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Rheault Project 2");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Controller instance = new Controller(painter);
    //Controller constructor with argument of painter instance
}
```

I skipped the Implements part since it's already clear you're overriding the superclass's method, you can even click on it in your IDE and it will go to the superclass method, to confirm it.

Finally I also looked at the run method. It doesn't overwrite anything since it doesn't exist in the superclass Application. Try clicking it and you'll see.

```
public void run
```

But maybe this is because I copied your code wrong. Well those are some of the things I found looking at your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your start() works, but I'm clueless as to why mine did not as it's almost identical.

Removing @.Override from run() (as @.Override is something I never learned the theory on and I was just monkey coding it, school is wonderful) does remove the error but leaves me with InterruptedExceptions on every thread.sleep(). I will work on replacing those when I come back tonight, hopefully there'll be more answers then.
Thank you much friend for not flaming me for asking a question about a class project.

Comment: The reason to why my Start method works is because I removed Implements. Your method -> public void start(Stage primaryStage) implements Application throws Exception and my method -> public void start(javafx.stage.Stage primaryStage) throws Exception    You don't need to say that it is implementing Application. It's redundant to do so in the method. That's the difference. And no problems! If you want you can always give me an upvote. If you need any more help outside of the answers you get, you can always contact me too. Learning shouldn't be flamed for :D

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an assignment so I don't know what's needed and what's not. If you don't need `Threads`, don't use them. If you can use `Timeline`, I would recommend using it. This sample app most likely doesn't do what you need it to do but hopefully, it can help.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication335 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), (ActionEvent event1) -> {
            gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
            gc.strokeOval(150, 150, 100, 100);  //circle
            System.out.println("running 1");
        }), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(6), (ActionEvent event1) -> {
            gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);   //For purposes of this program, blank background, clearing rectangle works
            gc.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            gc.strokeRect(100, 100, 100, 100);  //Square
            System.out.println("running 2");
            //java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);
        }), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(9), (ActionEvent event1) -> {
            gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
            gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            gc.strokeText("Course # and Title", 100, 140);  //Text, approximately centered
            System.out.println("running 3");
            //java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);
        }), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(12), (ActionEvent event1) -> {
            gc.clearRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
            System.out.println("running 4");
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            timeline.play();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new VBox(canvas, btn));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thread.sleep() isn't required so I will switch it out, thank you for the demo. People are touchy about school projects being posted here so I want to demonstrate that I've actually put in the effort in solving this. (5 hours of effort.) 
Are you guys saying there were mostly logic errors with what I put forward?

Comment: You need to rethink `@Override
    public void run() { 
    while(true) { ` and `public class Controller extends Thread {`